# How to reverse the "transistor path" in circuitikz?

Tags: circuitikz

I discovered the existence of the "transistor path" in circuitikz, which was very useful but had a strange behaviour:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{circuitikz}[american]
        \draw (0, 0) node[anchor=east]{$V_-$} to[short, o-o] ++(4, 0);
        \draw (2, 0) to[Tnpn, mirror] ++(0, 2);
        \draw (0, 2) node[anchor=east]{$V_+$} to[short, o-o] ++(4, 0);
    \end{circuitikz}
    \caption{My first circuit.}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This generates:

[image]

which looks fine, but constructing the code is "backwards". The transistor path goes from emitter to collector, or from V- to V+. The mental model for circuits tends to be from V+ to V-, top to bottom.

Can this be reversed, so that the transistor path goes from collector to the emitter for an npn transistor?

Comment: Perhaps ```ìnvert``` instead of ```mirror``` in the ```Tnpn``` command?

Answer (score 4):

As [Luis Sibaja commented](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/575586/how-to-reverse-the-transistor-path-in-circuitikz#comment1449504_575586), if you want to reverse the standard direction (which is that one because... it happened, really), you can use `invert`.

If you get bored by using all this invert you can use the power of Ti*k*Z styles:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\ctikzsetstyle{romano}
\tikzset{npnT/.style={Tnpn, invert}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[american]
        \draw (0, 1) to[Tnpn, l=A] ++(2, 0);
        \draw (0, 0) to[npnT, l=B] ++(2, 0);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]