# transistor not showing

Tags: circuitikz

I am using circuit tikz to draw a diode in series with a transistor using the following:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{circuitikz}[american, line width=0.3, line cap=round, line join=round]
    \ctikzset{diodes/scale=0.6}
    \draw (0,0) to[D] (2,0) to[nigbt] (4,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{figure}
```

I don't get why the transistor is not drawn?

Comment: Interesting! I thought `\pgf@circ@definetranspath{nigbt}` was supposed to treat it like a bipole (emitter to collector).

Comment: @JohnKormylo to have the path-style transistor you need to add a T to the name... `... to[Tnigbt] ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path-style transistors must be specified by adding a `T` to the name. So, try with

```
... to[Tnigbt] ...
```

[image: manual about transistor path]

See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/575630/38080 (never accepted, but...)

Answer (score 2):

Symbol for transistor is not dipol, but is defined as node:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american, line width=0.3, line cap=round, line join=round]
    \ctikzset{diodes/scale=0.6}
    \draw (0,0) to[D] (2,0) node[nigbt, anchor=B] {} ;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: no, it's not in style romano, it's in base `circuitikz`. ;-). I added the relevant part of the manual (page 118 for 1.6.1)

Comment: @Rmano, now I'm a bit confused. I need to read package documentation again and again ,,,